# anti-clockwise pathed curve for connecting nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I have a question which is no doubt simple to most people but I have been struggling with it for a while now. I have the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

% Add information on the process above the thermocline
\node [text width=1cm,align=center,font = \scriptsize] (A) at (7.5,6) {A};
\node [text width=1cm,align=center,font = \scriptsize]  (B) at (6.5,5.5) {B};
\node [text width=1cm,align=center,font = \scriptsize] (C) at (7.5,4.75) {C};
\node [text width=1cm,align=center,font = \scriptsize]  (D) at (8.5,5.5) {D};

\draw [->] (A.west)--(B.north);
\draw [->] (B.south)--(C.west);
\draw [->] (C.east)--(D.south);
\draw [->] (D.north)--(A.east);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

which returns:

[image]

How can I alter these lines so they are curved, furthermore I would like it to be almost a circle where the nodes are written on top of the curved path thus resulting in gaps in the circle where these nodes are placed.

Comment: have you seen the diagram at the top of page 48 of [the manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is something similar to what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3cm, thick,main node/.style={font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}]
  \node[main node] (1) {A};
  \node[main node] (2) [below left of=1] {B};
  \node[main node] (3) [below right of=2] {C};
  \node[main node] (4) [below right of=1] {D};

  \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
    (1) edge [bend right] node[left] {} (2)
    (2) edge [bend right] node[left] {} (3)
    (3) edge [bend right] node[right] {} (4)
    (4) edge [bend right] node[right] {} (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

resulting in:

[image]

The is a modified example of [TeXample](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/graph/).