# Make graph where nodes and connecting edges are circles

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, nodes, graphs, circles

I am struggling to figure out how to make a graph that connects 12 circular nodes in a circle. I have the code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph [nodes={draw, circle}, clockwise, radius=3in, nodes, n=12] {
subgraph C_n [name=outer]
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which gives me this: 
[image]
but I would like the edges connecting them to be curved so that it resembles a circle rather than a dodecahedron. Since this issue is similar to [anti-clockwise pathed curve for connecting nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95248/anti-clockwise-pathed-curve-for-connecting-nodes) I tried replicating that code, but with 12 nodes instead of four, which gave me a square. The only advantage to this method was that I was able to start the nodes at 0 rather than 1, as I would like to do in my final product.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3cm,    thick,main node/.style={circle,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}]
\node[main node] (1) {0};
\node[main node] (2) [below right of=1] {1};
\node[main node] (3) [below right of=2] {2};
\node[main node] (4) [below right of=3] {3};
\node[main node] (5) [below left of=4] {4};
\node[main node] (6) [below left of=5] {5};
\node[main node] (7) [below left of=6] {6};
\node[main node] (8) [above left of=7] {7};
\node[main node] (9) [above left of=8] {8};
\node[main node] (10) [above left of=9] {9};
\node[main node] (11) [above right of=10] {t};
\node[main node] (12) [above right of=11] {e};

\path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
(1) edge [bend right] node[right] {} (2)
(2) edge [bend right] node[right] {} (3)
(3) edge [bend right] node[right] {} (4)
(4) edge [bend right] node[right] {} (5);
(5) edge [bend right] node[right] {} (6)
(6) edge [bend right] node[right] {} (7)
(7) edge [bend right] node[right] {} (8)
(8) edge [bend right] node[right] {} (9);
(9) edge [bend right] node[right] {} (10)
(10) edge [bend right] node[right] {} (11)
(11) edge [bend right] node[right] {} (12)
(12) edge [bend right] node[right] {} (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Is there a way to make both the nodes and edges circular?

Comment: I think polar coordinates to insert nodes is better than relative positioning.

Comment: This example does not use the graphdrawing library: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/381283

Answer (score 6):

What about:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphs.standard}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph [nodes={draw, circle}, clockwise, radius=3in, nodes, n=12, edge={bend left=12}] {
subgraph C_n [name=outer]
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit:** after again reading your question, I found that you want to start with 0. So, possibly this is an acceptable solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphs.standard}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph [nodes={draw, circle, minimum width=.25in, inner sep=0pt}, clockwise, radius=1in, nodes, n=12, V={0,...,11}, ->, edge={bend left=10,>=stealth}] {
subgraph C_n [name=outer]
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In my opinion you could edit your answer and keep only the last solution, which is much better than the others. Good job!

Comment: Very nice! (+1) You may benefit by replacing `bend=10` by `bend=12` in the upper two examples.

Comment: @Sigur: I removed the second example, as this was merely the same as the first, just with arrow heads added. marmot: I edited the first example accordingly. Thanks!